# pdfmake prints a unknown character for toLocaleString

Tags: javascript, locale, pdfmake

I am using pdfmake to generate a pdf and I need to use toLocaleString("fr-Fr") but this prints a unknown character in the pdf.

You can try it here: http://pdfmake.org/playground.html

the code is

```
var y = Number(120000);
var x = y.toLocaleString("fr-FR").toString();
var dd = {
    content: [
        x.toString()
    ]
    
}
```

Please check the output on the right side of the image. Can some one please guide me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We were able to fix this by using Arimo font from Google Fonts.
This [page](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202f/fontsupport.htm) lists all the fonts that support the "narrow no-break space" character.